# Change labels length in a plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggalluvial

I try to run this option of a plot:

```
library(ggalluvial)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(status = c("open", "close", "close", "open/close", "close"), 
                 stock = c("google", "amazon", "amazon", "yahoo", "amazon"), 
                 newspaper = c("times", "newyork", "london", "times", "times"))

# Count the number of occurance for each alluvial
df <- df %>% dplyr::group_by(stock, newspaper, status) %>% 
  summarise(n = n()) 

# Define the factors
df$status <- factor(df$status, levels = c("open", "open/close", "close"))
df$stock <- factor(df$stock, levels = c("google", "amazon", "yahoo"))
df$newspaper <- factor(df$newspaper, levels = c("times", "newyork", "london"))

# Plot the alluvial as in https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggalluvial/vignettes/ggalluvial.html#alluvia-wide-format
ggplot2::ggplot(df.2, aes(y = n, axis1 = stock, axis2 = newspaper)) +
  ggalluvial::geom_alluvium(aes(fill = status), width = 1/12) +
  ggalluvial::geom_stratum(width = 1/12, fill = "black", color = "grey") +
  ggplot2::geom_label(stat = "stratum", aes(label = after_stat(stratum))) +
  ggplot2::scale_x_discrete(limits = c("stock", "newspaper"), expand = c(.05, .05)) +
  ggplot2::scale_fill_brewer(type = "qual", palette = "Set1") +
  ggplot2::ggtitle("Alluvial-Test")
```

Is there any command which can reduce the labels of this two columns stock and newspaper?

Answer (score 2):

You could change the `size` in `geom_label` like this:

```r
library(ggalluvial)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(status = c("open", "close", "close", "open/close", "close"), 
                 stock = c("google", "amazon", "amazon", "yahoo", "amazon"), 
                 newspaper = c("times", "newyork", "london", "times", "times"))

# Count the number of occurance for each alluvial
df <- df %>% dplyr::group_by(stock, newspaper, status) %>% 
  summarise(n = n()) 
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'stock', 'newspaper'. You can override
#> using the `.groups` argument.

# Define the factors
df$status <- factor(df$status, levels = c("open", "open/close", "close"))
df$stock <- factor(df$stock, levels = c("google", "amazon", "yahoo"))
df$newspaper <- factor(df$newspaper, levels = c("times", "newyork", "london"))

# Plot the alluvial as in https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggalluvial/vignettes/ggalluvial.html#alluvia-wide-format
ggplot2::ggplot(df, aes(y = n, axis1 = stock, axis2 = newspaper)) +
  ggalluvial::geom_alluvium(aes(fill = status), width = 1/12) +
  ggalluvial::geom_stratum(width = 1/12, fill = "black", color = "grey") +
  ggplot2::geom_label(stat = "stratum", aes(label = after_stat(stratum)), size = 2) +
  ggplot2::scale_x_discrete(limits = c("stock", "newspaper"), expand = c(.05, .05)) +
  ggplot2::scale_fill_brewer(type = "qual", palette = "Set1") +
  ggplot2::ggtitle("Alluvial-Test")
#> Warning: Using the `size` aesthetic in this geom was deprecated in ggplot2 3.4.0.
#> ℹ Please use `linewidth` in the `default_aes` field and elsewhere instead.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

This is at least a known issue. And there are several solutions presented [here](https://corybrunson.github.io/ggalluvial/articles/labels.html). I personally like the solution with `ggfittext`. Here is how I tried to solve your problem. Note the solution by @Quinten is also very good:

We could fit the black color with alpha=...:

```
#install.packages("ggfittext")
library(ggfittext)
library(ggalluvial)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
# Plot the alluvial as in https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggalluvial/vignettes/ggalluvial.html#alluvia-wide-format
ggplot2::ggplot(df, aes(y = n, axis1 = stock, axis2 = newspaper, label=after_stat(stratum))) +
  ggalluvial::geom_alluvium(aes(fill = status), width = 1/12) +
  geom_stratum(width = 1/12, fill="black", color="grey") +
  ggfittext::geom_fit_text(stat = "stratum", width = 1/12, min.size = 3, color="grey") +
  ggplot2::scale_x_discrete(limits = c("stock", "newspaper"), expand = c(.05, .05)) +
  ggplot2::scale_fill_brewer(type = "qual", palette = "Set1") +
  ggplot2::ggtitle("Alluvial-Test")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think a nicer result would be obtained from `geom_text` at 90 degrees rotation:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(y = n, axis1 = stock, axis2 = newspaper)) +
  geom_alluvium(aes(fill = status), width = 1/12, color = "white", size = 2) +
  geom_stratum(width = 1/12, fill = "gray30", color = "white", size = 2) +
  geom_text(stat = "stratum", aes(label = after_stat(stratum), angle = 90),
            color = "white", size = 8) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("stock", "newspaper"), expand = c(.05, .05)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(type = "qual", palette = "Set1") +
  ggtitle("Alluvial-Test") +
  theme_void(base_size = 20) +
  theme(plot.margin = margin(20, 20, 20, 20))
```

[image]